# Java8: foreach set and calling a method with a parameter

Tags: java-8

I'm struggling coming out with the right syntax for this:

I have this functionalInterface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Observer {
    void notifyMe(Packet p);
};
```

and I'm trying to make the following call:

```
packet -> observers.forEach(Observer::notifyMe);
```

it doesn't compile! any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: `packet -> observers.forEach(o -> o.notifyMe(packet));` ?

Comment: Thanks ! I was close but you nailed it.